# Why is indexOf returning the wrong value?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Long time reader, first time poster, so apologies in advance!

I’m working in Google Sheets, and currently have two spreadsheets. One has a reference number (chunk) on the Home page, the other (TEMP_ID) has a list of reference numbers. When I run the function, it should use the index of the reference number to mark the cell next to it on the list as “TRUE”.

```
var chunk = DS_Home.getRange(‘E6’).getValue().toString()
var temp = SpreadsheetApp.openById(TEMP_ID)
var temp_sheet = temp.getSheetByName(‘Genie’)
var temp_chunks = temp_sheet.getRange(‘A2:A’).getValues().toString()
var index = temp_chunks.indexOf(chunk)
temp_sheet.getRange(index+2,2,1,1).setValue(‘TRUE’)
```

2080 is in cell A4, which should be an index of 2 since it is the 3rd value in the array. For some reason it is returning an index of 10, which is 5465. In debug, everything looks correct until I get to index: 10. Chunk is 2080, temp_chunks is “2690, 5007, 2080, 1899, 3879, 4005, 1711, 2848, 2834, 2993, 5465, 2826, 5507, 1731…” and it continues on from there. If I don’t .toString() it returns an index of -1. What else can I try, or what else do I need to understand to have the result I expect?

I tried changing the array to a string, changing the chunk to a string, tried checking for duplicates in the list, tried checking other chunks to see if they pull correctly and most don’t seem to (1899 returns 15, despite having an index of 3 from being 4th in the array).

I expect that if I count the first item in the list as 0, the number the item is should match the index.

Comment: That can't be your actual code, since it contains slanted quotes instead of straight quotes. Please post again, turning off "Smart Quotes" in your editor.

Comment: `temp_chunks` is a string, not an array. So it's returning the index in characters.

Comment: `2080` starts at the 10th character in the string.

Comment: `.getValues().toString()` this is probably not what you want

Answer (score 2):

`temp_chunks` is a string, so `indexOf()` returns the position in characters of the substring. You should use the array returned by `getValues()`, rather than converting it to a string.

```
let temp_chunks = temp_sheet.getRange(‘A2:A’).getValues().map(col => col[0]);
let index = temp_chunks.indexOf(chunk);
```

Comment: Thank you! I apologize, I’m posting from mobile, very new to Javascript, and mostly self-taught. When I don’t convert it to a string, it returned an index of -1?

Answer (score 1):

This is not intended to be answer.  I'm just trying to show you why you should not be using ranges like "A2:A" in google apps script.

```
function testfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
}
```

This is what is  actually returned from a sheet that has approximately 250 rows of numbers.

```
Execution log
5:13:59 PM  Notice  Execution started
5:13:59 PM  Info    [["COL1"],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31],[32],[33],[34],[35],[36],[37],[38],[39],[40],[41],[42],[43],[44],[45],[46],[47],[48],[49],[50],[51],[52],[53],[54],[55],[56],[57],[58],[59],[60],[61],[62],[63],[64],[65],[66],[67],[68],[69],[70],[71],[72],[73],[74],[75],[76],[77],[78],[79],[80],[81],[82],[83],[84],[85],[86],[87],[88],[89],[90],[91],[92],[93],[94],[95],[96],[97],[98],[99],[100],[101],[102],[103],[104],[105],[106],[107],[108],[109],[110],[111],[112],[113],[114],[115],[116],[117],[118],[119],[120],[121],[122],[123],[124],[125],[126],[127],[128],[129],[130],[131],[132],[133],[134],[135],[136],[137],[138],[139],[140],[141],[142],[143],[144],[145],[146],[147],[148],[149],[150],[151],[152],[153],[154],[155],[156],[157],[158],[159],[160],[161],[162],[163],[164],[165],[166],[167],[168],[169],[170],[171],[172],[173],[174],[175],[176],[177],[178],[179],[180],[181],[182],[183],[184],[185],[186],[187],[188],[189],[190],[191],[192],[193],[194],[195],[196],[197],[198],[199],[200],[201],[202],[203],[204],[205],[206],[207],[208],[209],[210],[211],[212],[213],[214],[215],[216],[217],[218],[219],[220],[221],[222],[223],[224],[225],[226],[227],[228],[229],[230],[231],[232],[233],[234],[235],[236],[237],[238],[239],[240],[241],[242],[243],[244],[245],[246],[247],[248],[249],[250],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""],[""]]
5:14:01 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

See all the nulls at the end.

If you do it this way:

```
function testfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange("A1:A" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
}
```

You wont get all of the nulls.

You can use indeterminate ranges like that if you use the Sheets API.  It seems to be a little smarter than core google apps script.

Like this:

```
function testfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const rg = sh.getRange("A1:A")
  const vs = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss.getId(),`${sh.getName()}!${rg}`).values;
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand that better. I’ve seen that concept but never understood the application of it. I’m used to writing in-cell functions in Google Sheets, so coming to AppScript, I didn’t see why it wouldn’t be optimal to use the whole row as a reference. I’ll keep that in mind!